# После создания массива, программа почему-то опять спрашивает его длину

Tags: c#

Программа должна работать так:

Спрашивает у пользователя длину массива, пользователь вводит.
Спрашивает какой тип массива нужен юзеру (int или string), пользователь выбирает. Дальше создаётся массив с нужным типом данных, и длинной, которую он указал выше. И потом программа просто пишет Finish!

В чём непонятная ошибка программы? В том, что после создания массива, она почему-то опять спрашивает его длину... И только потом пишет Finish!
Почему так происходит? Вроде всё правильно написал...

Вот код:

```
using System;

namespace Launcher
{
    class Program
    {


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dlin_ARRAY();
            tip_ARRAY();
            Console.WriteLine("Finish!");
            Console.Read();     
        }
        public static int dlin_ARRAY()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введи длину массива");
            Console.WriteLine(">>>"); 
            int userinput_dlin_ARRAY = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            Console.WriteLine("<<<");
            return userinput_dlin_ARRAY;
        }
        public static void tip_ARRAY()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введи цифру типа массива, который тебе нужен");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Integer");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Stringer");
            bool isTrue = true;
            while (isTrue) {
            Console.WriteLine(">>>"); 
            int userinput_tip_ARRAY = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            Console.WriteLine("<<<");
            if (userinput_tip_ARRAY == 1) 
            {
                int[] array = new int[dlin_ARRAY()];
            }
            else if (userinput_tip_ARRAY == 2)
            {
                string[] array = new string[dlin_ARRAY()];
            }
            else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Не верно, введи 1 или 2");
                    continue;
            }
            isTrue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы результат исполнения метода `dlin_ARRAY()` никуда не записываете и не передаете в следующий метод, в котором заново вызываете метод: `new int/string[dlin_ARRAY()]`. Так что багов нет. Программа делает ровно то, что Вы написали

Comment: Посчитайте сколько раз вы вызываете метод `dlin_ARRAY()`, и поймете, почему он длину много раз спрашивает

Comment: Ну это понятно что я этот метод каким-то образом несколько раз вызываю , только мне не понятно как сделать чтобы он один раз выполнялся только в Main () ...

Comment: @ТихонФедулов я же написал Вам. Закэшируйте результат его исполнения в Main и передайте в качестве параметра в Ваш второй метод, где подставьте переданное значение вместо вызовов метода

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно подметили в комментариях, у вас не используется возвращаемое значение метода `dlin_Array()`. И потом вы снова вызываете этот метод, причем если вы в первый раз вводите 3 при определении типа массива, у вас метод `dlin_Array` будет вызван по крайней мере 3 раза.

Я бы вызывал его в методе `tip_Array` и присваивал переменной:

```
using System;

namespace Launcher
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            tip_ARRAY();
            Console.WriteLine("Finish!");
            Console.Read();     
        }
        public static void tip_ARRAY()
        {
            var lengthArray = dlin_ARRAY();
            Console.WriteLine("Введи цифру типа массива, который тебе нужен");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Integer");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Stringer");

            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>"); 
                int userinput_tip_ARRAY = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
                Console.WriteLine("<<<");
                if (userinput_tip_ARRAY == 1) 
                {
                    int[] array = new int[lengthArray];
                    break;
                }
                else if (userinput_tip_ARRAY == 2)
                {
                    string[] array = new string[lengthArray];
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Не верно, введи 1 или 2");
                }
            }
        }
        public static int dlin_ARRAY()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введи длину массива");
            Console.WriteLine(">>>"); 
            int userinput_dlin_ARRAY = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            Console.WriteLine("<<<");
            return userinput_dlin_ARRAY;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не критично конечно, но зачем его там вызывать? Почему бы не передать туда результат его выполнения?

Comment: @tym32167 Согласно Мартину ""Аргументы функций"
В идеальном случае количество аргументов функции равно нулю (нуль-арная функция). Далее следуют функции с одним аргументом (унарные) и с двумя аргументами (бинарные). Функций с тремя аргументами (тернарных) следует по возможности избегать. Необходимость функций с большим количеством аргументов (полиарных) должна быть подкреплена очень высокими доводами - и все равно такие функции лучше не использовать."

Comment: Ну, Мартин, его рекомендации, бесспорно, в основной массе свой полезны,но он не всегда прав (особенно его рекомендации по добавлению состояния вместо добавления параметра метода), потому делать какие то вещи просто потому что так дядя Боб сказал - не стоит. К тому же, он же писал, что функция должна делать только 1 функциональную вещь, а вы, по сути, добавили функции ответственность вызывать другую функцию без какой либо необходимости, что в теории нарушает SRP (и функция уже не соответствует своему названию). Но, как я уже сказал, это не критично, мне было интересно ваше мнение, спасибо :)

Comment: @tym32167 Я не стал очень сильно модифицировать код автора, ибо это запутало бы его (автора). И я не стал вводить лишний аргумент в функцию, что в свою очередь опять усложняет понимание функции (пусть и незначительно).

Comment: @tym32167 зачем нам вводить лишний аргумент в функцию (выделять под него память), если мы можем выбрать такую архитектуру приложения, при которой можем обойтись без введения этого аргумента? Точно по этой же причине я убрал булевую переменную `isTrue` из кода автора.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо :). Ну, так и запишем. Дискутировать тут скорее всего смысла не имеет, сами понимаете, и вопрос не об этом, и код в ответе и так есть куда менять, даже если делать всё по Фаулеру.

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен, если всё делать по Фаулеру- этот код можно очень долго полировать. Напоследок хотелось сделать еще одно замечание- так как мы передаем аргумент в функцию по значению, в этом случае у нас на стеке данная переменная будет сохранятся до самого конца выполнения метода `Main`, при использовании переменной внутри метода как описано выше, переменная на стеке будет сохранена до конца выполнения метода `tip_ARRAY`, и после завершения метода указатель вершины стека сместится на место последнего удаленного элемента. Что не критично для такого короткоживущего приложения, но всё же.

Comment: Да, про стеки все понятно, однако имхо об этом надо думать, когда есть проблема с этим. Например, я за 10 лет разного энтерпрайза и не очень довольно редко применял такие знания. В основном, к сожалению, если до оптимизации и доходит, то они выглядят как смена алгоритма (в прошлом году только поменял List на Dictionary в одном из legacy проектов и операция вместо 30 мин стала занимать 3 секунды). Я к тому, что знать что там со стеком, конечно, хорошо, но навряд ли это пригодится среднестатистическому прогеру и оно не имеет никакого значения в вашем коде :)

Comment: @tym32167 Да, в этом коде я с вами согласен. Вопрос исчерпан.